# I don't know how search in a table with zebra pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I want search in a table in html and mysql, but I have the table with zebra_pagination and I don't know how implement a search, filter with the table... and zebra pagination

Comment: zebra is done using html/css, after the results are fetched from mysql. So if you already have zebra pagination. don't worry just get the search results correctly

Comment: but I want do a table like datatable jquery.... but with zebra_pagination